# How to trigger GitHub Action workflow based on several workflows

Tags: github, github-actions

Suppose i have three workflows: `build_backend`, `build_frontend` and `deploy`. First two should trigger in parallel, but the third should only trigger when **both** of those workflows are finished.

Currently the `deploy` workflow triggers twice -- i suspect that's for each of the two workflows completed.

```
# .github/workflows/build-xxx.yml
name: Build and Test - Backend

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
# ...
```

```
# .github/workflows/deploy.yml
name: Deploy

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows:
      - "Build and Test - Backend"
      - "Build and Test - Frontend"
    types:
      - completed
    branch: master

jobs:
  deploy:
# ...
```

I haven't found the solution in docs:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions

Comment: It's not possible to do exactly what you want with GHA using many workflows. Currently, you can only trigger a workflow from **one** other workflow using the [workflow_run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) trigger. Therefore, a workaround could be to gather the `build_backend` and the `build_frontend` in the same workflow, in different jobs, and then trigger the other workflow based on the result of this one. You could also get the same result by using a `dispatch event` at the end of the 1st workflow to trigger the 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub actions does not support specific trigger definitions like this for whole workflows.

However, you can use the [needs keyword](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds) on a job level. So if you could consolidate all of these workflows into one workflow file. It seems like like this could work for you since these workflows all have the same (branch) trigger and the buildxxx are only a single job each.

There is also a GitHub Roadmap item describing, that they are working on adding workflow partials. That would enable you to separte these parts out in the future if you want to, but that is not avilable yet it seems like.